# Trying to run a program in Eclipse, it's asking for an ant build?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

novice programmer here. I'm working on a small project, and I've started it on my PC. I uploaded it to GitHub, and then opened it on my laptop so I can edit it there. My program runs on my PC, but when I try to run it using Eclipse on my laptop, it asks me which Ant Build to run as. I have no idea what an ant build is, and I don't have this issue on my PC (and both are running Eclipse).

I went to my system properties and set JAVA_HOME to my JDK and selected that same one in preferences in Eclipse, but that didn't seem to help either. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an updated jdk, then update your apache ant, have you tried to run your project under ant? Run As->...Ant Build.. something like that.
Or try to re-import your project to your eclipse.

Comment: I actually have no idea what an apache ant is, but when I go to Run As -> nothing shows up. I tried reimporting, but Eclipse was acting really strange so I'm reinstalling it and seeing it from there.